# How do I change the color of points using QGIS based on a value?

Tags: qgis

I have a delimited text layer of latitude and longitude points. I have put them on a map (see image). How do I change the color of the points depending on their "threat" value (see data table)? I was hoping to make the point color darker the higher the threat level is. Sorry, I am new to QGIS and I am not sure how to start going about doing this.

[image: Map]

[image: Data format]

Comment: I deleted it, sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click your layer, choose properties, go to symbology. Then choose "graduated" from the dropdown menu. Choose "Threat" as column. In case it is not recognized, you can use to_real() to turn the strings into a number. Then click "classify".

[image]

Comment: Where do you use the `to_real()` function? It's that in the attribute calculator?

Comment: In the value column. Instead of "threat" use to_real("threat").

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!